# Boost Weak_Ptr: Destruction is more expensive than expected

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, boost

For whatever reason, we're seeing quite a bit of cost from destroying weak pointers.  Here's the culprit code:

```
~weak_count() // nothrow  
{  
    if(pi_ != 0) pi_->weak_release();  // Consumes a huge chunk of our time.
#if defined(BOOST_SP_ENABLE_DEBUG_HOOKS)  
    id_ = 0;  
#endif  
}
```

We aren't in debug mode, and the debug hooks aren't engaged.  Weak release is consuming a truly phenomenal amount of time.  Is this a known issue?  Are we doing something wrong?

Boost version: 1.36
Compiler: VS2008 Compiler Suite.

We are locked into this Boost version for a variety of reasons, unfortunately, so I'm more wondering if these kind of bizarre expenditures are duplicable on newer versions, or represent the result of a known bad practice.  We are only destroying on the order of 500k weak pointers, which should not produce a noticeable difference in performance from destroying a similar number of raw pointers.  Certainly not a 2.5-4x increase in cost.  Note that we are not deleting the objects targeted by said pointers.  This expense is exclusively derived from the destruction of the pointers themselves.

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm guessing you got the sp_counted_base that does the atomic inc/decrement.  Thread-safe, at a very low level and great cost.  Step into weak_release and let us know.

Comment: Looks likely, will check more carefully when I have time.  But why would you do that for a weak_ptr?  The whole point of the weak_ptr is that it doesn't really f' about with the reference count, I thought?  In fact, shouldn't a weak_ptr be basically just a PoD?

Comment: Yeah, it's running through the compiler intrinsic InterlockedDecrement.  Which is insane, as far as I am concerned.  Why is the weak_ptr counting references at all?

Comment: @Jake: The point of weak_ptr over raw pointers is that it can determine if the object still exists. Therefore it must be able to have the refcount of the shared_ptr. Therefore the allocation for the refcount must be kept around for as long as there are weak_ptrs around, and therefore the refcount itself needs to be refcounted.

Comment: No, nothing simple about reference counting when you use threads.  Incrementing a number safely is an untrivial task. C++ being agnostic about threads is a 15 year old problem, libraries are filled with 'worst case but always works' code and have fairly inevitable worst case perf.

Comment: That's true.  Thinking about it, a lot of interesting timing issues arise.  Thank you muchly, everyone.  I'm feeling much enlightened!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`weak_ptr` needs something like a `shared_ptr` to implement itself -- because it needs to be able to determine if the pointer still exists, it needs to have a reference counted structure somewhere that maintains it's own refcounts.

I.e., how does the `weak_ptr` determine if the object still exists unless the reference count is kept available somehow for it to get to? :)

You might be able to get away with passing around raw pointers instead of `weak_ptr`s, if you don't need to actually ever take ownership in a piece of code using a `weak_ptr`.

Comment: So, effectively, the whole bit about "Weak_ptrs are no more expensive than raw pointers" is a flagrant lie?

Comment: @Jake: Who told you that? They're wrong. `Weak_ptr` is not, nor was ever intended, to be as efficient as a raw pointer.

Comment: And that will teach me to listen to professors. Ow.  I suppose if I had given it ten minutes of thought, I'd have quickly realized what was happening.  Rather shameful on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the cost comes from the atomic decrement of the reference count, which is fairly expensive compared to say, integer assignments, and could incur a cache (or to be very extreme, page) miss/fault, and being an atomic op, it also can incur things like cache line invalidations.

However, destroying a raw pointer is a no-op, so I'm not entirely sure what you were expecting from weak_ptr, but it's physically impossible for it to offer the same destruction cost if it offers any kind of destruction semantics.

Equally, it's more than possible that you're flat out overusing them. Ownership-enforcing pointers are not a silver bullet- you still have to think about who owns the object. The wide-scale use of a weak pointer suggests to me that you haven't really thought through your ownership semantics.

Finally, there's an implementation of shared_ptr and weak_ptr in MSVC 2008, in the std::tr1 namespace. You could try that.

Comment: Actually, in this case, the ownership semantics are pretty carefully laid out.  I'm not sure I disagree in the gist, however, and I did know there were some performance costs associated with weak_ptr.  I just didn't expect three orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Jake: That's just because you forgot how little (i.e., zero) raw pointers cost to destruct.